# How to setup home server?

Tags: windows-xp, home-server

I have an old desktop, laptop and a  wireless router (Belkin).

My desktop's specifications are

> 1. 512 MB RAM :p
> 2. 320 GB Harddisk
> 3. OS: Windows XP

I would like to use my desktop as a home server and use it to

> 1. Host my web page (local)
> 2. Store some files on it

Can that be done on Windows XP Home edition?

Comment: to those voting to close: this is about consumer-end setups, home networking, and home server setups.  please do not migrate this to Server Fault.

Comment: Is there any reason not to use Linux instead of Windows XP?

Comment: is think XP is more user friendly :p

Comment: XP is not a Server OS tho. Plus using linux the user could learn a bit more, and have less headaches like with a windows server (hotfixes/reboots, fragmentation, etc and so on).

Answer (score 5):

Apache is your best bet.  Any reason why you wouldn't want to try Ubuntu Linux?  It is very simple and there are tons of step-by-step instructions online for setting up a web server with Ubuntu.

Comment: +agreed... I really think Ubuntu would be a better way to go.  Especially with the 512MB of RAM.  And for the love of all that is holy, do not even think about using IIS :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/) as a web server (or may be [wampserver](http://www.wampserver.com/) if you need mysql/php) and you can store file and share them with windows sharing

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar setup w/ XP Pro sharing a printer and a USB drive, which are accessed from 2 laptops. I have lots of problems with XP "forgetting" which IDs can access those shared resources. I'm getting tired of rebuilding the shares because of XP's idiosyncrasies. I will be replacing XP with Linux soon (probably [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com).)

Answer (score 0):

try [nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/Main), lighter than apache